# How to recover my former account?

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts

This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702267/begueradj) is myself. I do not remember which email address I used for it. I wonder how can I get access to it, or get back its points to myself again.

Comment: contact stackoverflow team here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

The gist is that you'll need to edit the "About Me" section of your profile with "merge keep" and "merge delete" ("merge delete" will be merged into "merge keep").

Then, use the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page and describe your problem.

If you can't log into one of your accounts, you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) for a password reset email.

In your case, you'll need to include in your description of the issue to the Stack Exchange team that you forgot the email you used to create the original account since that's the only public-facing way to regain access to it (and you don't know what it is).